# The system cannot find the path specified. node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959

Tags: reactjs

PS D:\React training projects\React Routing project version 5 & 6\React Routing Project v6> npm start

> react-router-6-upgrade@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

The system cannot find the path specified.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\React training projects\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Answer (score 0):

If you cloned this code from some repository do `npm install` and try running `npm start`

Comment: Tried but no use....

Answer (score -1):

if you have done all the things that are mentioned on the internet like

- setting environment path
- restarting computer
  and still facing the issue then just uninstall the node and remove all the files related to node like in

C:/programfiles/nodejs
C:/user/%username%/AppData/Roaming/npm
C:/user/%username%/AppData/Roaming/node_modules

remove all the node_modules and npm related files
then remove all the environment variables related to npm and node
then restart